# Сайт разлогинивается автоматом и Job

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Добрый день!
Есть сайт ASP.net mvc. Есть 2 проблемы:
1.В нем создано стандартное решение из "коробки" по авторизации пользователей, единственное, то что было переделено, это переориентация на БД MySQL. Для моих нужд,используется только таблица "users".Если тестирую приложение на локалхосте то все ок, как только перенес на хостинг (reg.ru) начались проблемы с постоянным выбросом из кабинета, т.е. на сайте залогинился, открываю нужный контроллер, затем другой и тут же сайт разлогинивается и перебрасывает на страницу авторизации. Может это случится и сразу после того как залогинился, а может через время, но выкидывает всегда, хотя на локалхосте такого нет. Что может быть? Пробовал на разных браузерах, результат тот же самый.
2. Для одной из задач, необходимо чтобы сайт раз в n секунд, проверял входящую почту и если есть не прочитанные, делал необходимые действия. Каким функционалом это лучше сделать? я использую Quartz, т.е. создал класс и реализовал

```
Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
```

Затем описал в другом классе, старт джоба

```
public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<GetEmails>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("emails", "gr")     // идентифицируем триггер с именем и группой
            .StartNow()                            // запуск сразу после начала выполнения
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x            // настраиваем выполнение действия
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(60)          // через n секунд
                .RepeatForever())                   // бесконечное повторение
            .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

и в Global.asax прописал

```
EmailSheduler.Start();
```

Соответственно содержимое файла:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        EmailSheduler.Start();            
    }
```

Проблема: если я обновляю страницу на хостинге, обращаюсь к сайту, в общем что-то делаю, то все работает, но если никого нет,нет подключений, или страница долго висит, то jobы не выполняются.
Каким образом можно исправить проблему, чтобы в независимости от того есть ли активное подключение или нет, выполнялись джобы?или использовать что-то другое? (сразу если можно пример)

Comment: "Global.asax прописал" - где Вы это прописали, мы должны сами догадаться?

Comment: в проекте есть файл,называется Global.asax.cs, в методе Application_Start() добавил старт своего джоба.

Comment: 1) Возможно, проблема в том, что запросы уходят на несколько машин, а в конфигах не указан "статический" ключ машины. Вообщем, если сайт развернут на нескольких машинах, то https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager/     2) фоновые обработчики - это работа не для сайта. Напишите простую windows-службу и скопипастите туда код. Веб-сервера обычно останавливают пулы сайтов, если к ним нет обращений и все ваши джобы умирают))

Comment: 1. Спасибо, заработало. Не знал,спасибо. 2. Я понимаю что фоновые задачи не для сайта, нужно решение для клиента, чтобы отдать ПО, а написание отдельной windows-службы тоже ставит под вопрос, куда её вешать? на какую машину? итд итп